# 'for' loop variable not releasing on loop iterations

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting

Been wrecking my brain all night trying to figure out why this isn't working, but one of my variables isn't releasing on the next iteration of my loop and I can't figure out why... The first pass of the loop seems to work fine, but the next iteration, the first variable gets locked and the script connects to the system that's already been configured.

I've been staring at this for a while now and no matter how I approach it, it still behaves badly. :/ The purpose is to read a text-string of a given file, and use it to modify (via Find and Replace (fnr.exe)) another file with several instances of the required data. I didn't have alot of luck with 'findstr' replacing so many instances of the text required so I went with a tool I've used before that seemed to work really well in it's previous scripting application...

Truth be told, I find myself stumbling with even the most basic code a lot of times, so any kind soul willing to impart some wisdom/assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

```
@ECHO ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

> "%~dp0report.log" ECHO Batch Script executed on %DATE% at %TIME%

rem read computer list line by line and do
FOR /F %%A in (%~dp0workstations.txt) do (
    SET lwn=
    SET WKSTN=%%A

    rem connect to workstation and read lwn.txt file
    pushd "\\%WKSTN%\c$\"

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
        FOR /F %%I in (\\%wkstn%\c$\support\lwn.txt) DO (
            SET LWN=%%I

            %~dp0fnr.exe --cl --dir "\\%WKSTN%\c$\support\folder\config" --fileMask "file.xml" --find "21XXXX" --replace "%%I"

            IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO Station %LWN%,Workstation %WKSTN%,Completed Successfully >> %~dp0report.log

            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Station %LWN%,Workstation %WKSTN%, A READ/WRITE ERROR OCCURRED >> %~dp0report.log
echo logwrite error 1 complete
            popd
        )
    )
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        ECHO ,,SYSTEM IS OFFLINE >> %~dp0report.log

        )
    popd
    set wkstn=
    set lwn=
    echo pop d complete
    )
msg %username% Script run complete...
eof
```

Comment: First, `if errorlevel 0` means if exit code of previous application is __greater or equal__ 0 which is always true. Put `if errorlevel 1` branch first and use `else` instead of `if errorlevel 0`. Or use `if not errorlevel 1` which means exit code is __lower than__  1, then ... For details see Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Comment: Second, I suppose that the batch file is not stored in a directory with a path containing anywhere a space character as otherwise `%~dp0` being used together with name of a file without surrounding double quotes would be a problem.

Comment: Third, to reference a value of an environment variable assigned within a __for__ or __if__ branch using delayed expansion you have to use exclamation marks instead of percent signs, i.e. `!WKSTN!` and `!LWN!`. Open a command prompt window, run there the command `set /?` and read entire output help carefully.

Comment: Fourth, `eof` in last line is not a command, remove it.

Comment: Fifth, `popd` is executed at least twice if `pushd` was successful, perhaps even more times depending on number of lines in `lwn.txt`. That is of course also not good.

Comment: Have you tried IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0

Comment: @Mofi -- Thanks for the reply. The above was my last attempt at getting this to work and had rewritten from memory after having left work for the night and returned to banging on it at home; Unsurprisingly, it failed similarly in all my previous attempts written in much simpler form and many times over... I'll keep at it, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Paul -- As Mofi indicated, enabling delayed expansion, I hadn't accounted for expansion variables in my previous attempts, but I had tried your suggestion in a previous attempt without the expansion enabled and variable that had also failed...

Comment: @Mofi, per my previous comment, since this was a rewrite of a rewrite of a rewrite, a few remnants of my testing/comments apparently made it into the post (loong night) that I hadn't intended, the extra popd and eof being an unintended consequence of my lack of sleep. I'll retest after removing those, but I'm pretty sure the behavior sticks... And yes, no spaces in the path. 

Using ERRORLEVEL 1 higher/lower didn't seem to have any impact on the resulting behavior in past attempts, but I'll look at it again -- I had tried both 'if not' and/or "'1' higher" in my previous rewrites of the script)

Answer (score 2):

The ! notation must be used on all variables that are changed inside the loop.

```
C:>type looptest.bat
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem read computer list line by line and do
FOR /F %%A in (%~dp0workstations.txt) do (
    SET WKSTN=%%A

    ECHO WKSTN is set to %WKSTN%
    ECHO WKSTN is set to !WKSTN!

    pushd "\\!WKSTN!\c$\"

    ECHO After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to %ERRORLEVEL%
    ECHO After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to !ERRORLEVEL!

    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO ,,SYSTEM IS OFFLINE
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Host !WKSTN! is available
    )

    popd
)
EXIT /B 0
```

The workstations.txt file contained the following. (I should not give out actual host names.)

```
LIVEHOST1
DEADHOST1
LIVEHOST2
```

The output is...

```
C:>call looptest.bat
WKSTN is set to
WKSTN is set to LIVEHOST1
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 0
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 0
Host LIVEHOST1 is available
WKSTN is set to
WKSTN is set to DEADHOST1
The network path was not found.
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 0
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 1
,,SYSTEM IS OFFLINE
WKSTN is set to
WKSTN is set to LIVEHOST2
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 0
After PUSHD, ERRORLEVEL is set to 0
Host LIVEHOST2 is available
```

Answer (score 2):

Although your code have several issues, the main one is the use of `%` instead of `!` when you access the value of variables modified inside a for loop (although you already have the "enabledelayedexpansion" part in setlocal command). However, I noted that you sometimes use the FOR replaceable parameter (like in `--replace "%%I"`) and sometimes you use the variable with the same value (`%LWN%`), so a simpler solution in your case would be to replace every `%VAR%` with its corresponding `%%A` for parameter.

I inserted this modification in your code besides a couple small changes that make the code simpler and clearer.

```
@ECHO ON
setlocal

> "%~dp0report.log" ECHO Batch Script executed on %DATE% at %TIME%

rem Read computer list line by line and do
FOR /F %%A in (%~dp0workstations.txt) do (

    rem Connect to workstation and read lwn.txt file
    pushd "\\%%A\c$\"

    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        FOR /F "usebackq" %%I in ("\\%%A\c$\support\lwn.txt") DO (

            %~dp0fnr.exe --cl --dir "\\%%A\c$\support\folder\config" --fileMask "file.xml" --find "21XXXX" --replace "%%I"

            IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                ECHO Station %%I,Workstation %%A,Completed Successfully >> %~dp0report.log
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO Station %%I,Workstation %%A, A READ/WRITE ERROR OCCURRED >> %~dp0report.log
                echo logwrite error 1 complete
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO ,,SYSTEM IS OFFLINE >> %~dp0report.log
    )

    popd
    echo pop d complete

)
msg %username% Script run complete...
```